# Creating a line effect that follows two dynamic spheres

Tags: python, effects, lines

I have two spheres that are moving in the space using python scripting. How can I create a line like effect between the spheres? I don't want to snap a cylinder to the center of a sphere as the positions of the spheres may vary and cylinder height may come up short. The effect I'm referring to is similar to the line-renderer effect from unity. Is it possible in blender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not confused, it's very easily done through the GN[image]